# Mongoose Async find all and update for each

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I have little tipping game. After a game is done I get all tips from the mongoose db and then I iterate over these tips with forEach.

For each of these tips I get the username and load the user from the mongoose db to increase the points of this user and after that save the user changes back to the db.

One user can have more than one tip.

```
Tips.find({...}).exec(function(err, gameTips) {

   gameTips.forEach(tip, i) => {

      User.findOne({
         username: tip.username
      }).exec(function(err, user) {

          user.points = user.points + 1;

          user.save(function(err) {
             console.log("Points were increased");
          });
      });
   });
}
```

Now my problem is that the findOne of the user is done before the save of the prev tip processing. So the points will not be increased correctly.

User: testUser has 4 tips |
Expected: testUser.points = 4; |
Current: testUser.points = 2;

Is there a possibility to do that asynchronously so that find and save for all users will be done one after another so that each time I do:

```
user.points = user.points +1;
```

I will have the updated points before increasing?

---

EDIT

Thanks for your hints. I've tried to adopt that and my code is now:

```
async function updateUserPoints(schedule) {
try {
    console.log("Load Schedules");
    const scheduleTips = await Tip.find({
        scheduleId: schedule._id,
        season: schedule.season
    });

    console.log(scheduleTips);

    if (scheduleTips.length) {

        for (const scheduleTip of scheduleTips) {
            console.log("Load User for scheduleTip: " + scheduleTip.tip);
            let user = await User.findOne({
                username: scheduleTip.username
            })

            console.log(user);
            if (user) {
                const winner = calculateWinner(schedule);
                const points = calculatePoints(scheduleTip, winner);

                console.log("WINNER: " + winner);
                console.log("POINTS: " + points);

                user.tippspiel.overallPoints = user.tippspiel.overallPoints + points;
                user.tippspiel.seasonPoints = user.tippspiel.seasonPoints + points;
                user.tippspiel.gameWeekPoints = user.tippspiel.gameWeekPoints + points;

                await user.update({ username: scheduleTip.username }, { $inc: { "tippspiel.overallPoints": points } }, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        logger.error("[Tippspiel-User]: " + err);
                    } else {
                        logger.info("[Tippspiel-User]: User tippspiel points were updated.");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
}

function calculateWinner(schedule) {
let winner;

if (schedule.homeScore > schedule.awayScore) {
    //Home wins
    winner = "home";
} else if (schedule.homeScore < schedule.awayScore) {
    //Away wins
    winner = "away";
} else if (schedule.homeScore == schedule.awayScore) {
    //Tie/Draw
    winner = "draw";
}
return winner;

}

function calculatePoints(scheduleTip, winner) {
const POINTS_CORRECT_WINNER = settings.tippspiel.pointsCorrectWinner;
const POINTS_CORRECT_DRAW = settings.tippspiel.pointsCorrectDraw;
//If user has tipped correct
if (scheduleTip.tip === winner) {
    let points = 0;

    if ((scheduleTip.tip === "home") || (scheduleTip.tip === "away")) {
        points = points + POINTS_CORRECT_WINNER;

    } else if (scheduleTip.tip === "draw") {
        points = points + POINTS_CORRECT_DRAW;
    }

    return points;
} else {
    return 0;
}
}
```

I will test it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that you use the previous points to calculate the next score, instead use the mongoDB [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator

Option 1 using callbacks, ugly and not readable at all

```
Tips.find({})
  .exec(function(err, gameTips) {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    gameTips.forEach(tip => {
      User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { username: tip.username },
        { $inc: { points: tip.points }}
      ).exec(function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
          console.error(err);
          return;
        }
        console.log("Points were increased");
      })
    })
  })
```

Option 2 using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), alot more readable with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
Tips.find({})
  .then(gameTips => Promise.all(gameTips.map(tip => User.updateOne(
    { username: tip.username},
    { $inc: { points: tip.points } }
  )))
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Points were increased");
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```

Option 3 using [`async` / `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), my favorite, simple and readable

```
async function run() {
  try {
    const gameTips = await Tips.find({});
    await Promise.all(gameTips.map(tip => User.updateOne(
      { username: tip.username},
      { $inc: { points: tip.points } }
    )));
    console.log("Points were increased");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use async code the way you are using it in `forEach`, it will not yield the desired results. You can use `for of` with `async await` for a cleaner code:

```
 async function updateTips() {
 try {
    const tips = await Tips.find({condition: 'condition'})
    if (tips.length) { // check for empty result
        for (const tip of tips) {
            let user = await User.findOne({ username: tip.username })
            if (user) {
                user.points = user.points + 1
                await user.save()
                console.log('Points were increased')
            }
        }
    }
 } catch (err) {
     // handle errors here
 }
}

updateTips()
```

Comment: After 2 days searching, your answer was the right one for me! Many thanks!